# Solve $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^{x+1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, schwartz-distributions

Solve $f(x)=\int_{x-1}^{x+1} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$.

When $f$ is a function, it looks like the only solution is $f(x)=0$. But what if we allow distributions, such as the Dirac delta?

Comment: $f(x) = A \cos(cx) + B \sin(cx)$ works where $c \approx 1.895494267$
is the positive solution of $c = 2 \sin c$.  There should also be
complex solutions $c$ of this equation, giving rise to further linearly
independent solutions $f(x) = (A \cos sx + B \sin sx) \, e^{tx}$
where $c = s+it$.

Comment: crossposted at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658615/solve-fx-int-x-1x1-ft-textdt

Answer (score 26, accepted):

By differentiating we obtain 
$$f'(x)=f(x+1)-f(x-1)$$
This type of equations was addressed in the MO question
[On equation f(z+1)-f(z)=f'(z)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114875/on-equation-fz1-fz-fz/114878#114878)
Let $\lambda$ be any (complex) root of the equation
$$\lambda=e^\lambda-e^{-\lambda},$$
which is equivalent to $z=2\sin z$, as Noam wrote.
to this $\lambda$ a solution $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ is associated.
So you have infinitely many exponential solutions. Any linear combination is
also a solution. Then, depending on your assumptions of $f$ you can consider various limits of those linear combinations in the appropriate topology for your
functions/distributions class.

Edit. For a complete theory of this kind of equations see "Fonctions moyenne-periodiques", a theory created by Delsart and Schwartz in 1940-s.
This is generalized in the modern theory of "equations of convolution-type", see,
for example Hormander, Linear Partial differential operators. In this theory one considers equations $u\star f=0$, where $u$ is a distribution. In your case,
$u=\delta-\chi,$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of $[-1,1]$. The method of solution is an appropriate version of Fourier--Laplace transform, depending on your class of functions/distributions. Ordinary Fourier transform of $u$ is $U(\lambda)=1-2\sin\lambda/\lambda$, whose roots give you the exponential solutions.

The question whether we obtain all solutions in this way is addressed by the Malgrange approximation theorem (Theorem 16.4.1 in Hormander).

Comment: If you want to get from your differentiated equation to the integral equation, the root had better be nonzero.

Comment: Sure. When you differentiate, Fourier transform obtains one new root, $0$.

Comment: See also http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/reports/2006/R374.pdf, equation (4).