# Differential equation problem

Tags: differential-equations

I am stuck on a problem for a while. How do I solve $f'(x)=-kf(x-1)$? Unlike normal questions which has $f(x)$ on the RHS, this has $f(x-1)$ which has me stumped.

Comment: Apply Fourier transform as in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114875/on-equation-fz1-fz-fz/114878#114878

Comment: Since, according to the question, the term $f(x-1)$ on the right hand side seems to be a source of confusion here, it might be worthwhile to mention that this is a special case of so-called [delay differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation).

Comment: Even simpler that Fourier Transform, use Laplace transform.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda_k$ be all roots of the equation $\lambda+ke^{-\lambda}=0$, real or complex. 
The general solution is a linear combination
$$f(x)=\sum_k c_ke^{\lambda_kx}$$
When $k=1/e$, there is a multiple root, $\lambda_0=-1$, add $cxe^{-x}$.