# How may I find all continuous and bounded functions g with the following property?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, functional-equations

> Find all continuous and bounded functions $g$
> with :
> $$\forall x \in \mathbb R, 4g(x)=g(x+1)+g(x-1)+g(x+\pi)+g(x-\pi).$$

I have posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4630194/x-ens-functional-equation), but received no answer.

Comment: MO is the wrong place to repost unanswered questions *of this nature*

Comment: I have try in others forums, but no body have an idea

Comment: seems only constant function

Comment: "Very difficult" phrase makes me smile and quitting reading the rest of the text right away.

Comment: If view it in a two dimension space, then the structure is discrete harmonic function, but it is bounded so it is constant.

Comment: @Dattier, seems this already give a proof, and we can weekend the condition bounded to sublinear growth, the answer is still only constant function.

Comment: @WlodAA, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440179/a-very-difficult-functional-equation#comment1135374_440179), I agree; such editorialising does not belong in MO titles.  I edited it out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

$\newcommand\de\delta$Considering $g$ a distribution (in the generalized-function sense), let $\hat g$ be the Fourier transform of $g$. Then your functional equation yields
$$4\hat g(t)=e^{it}\hat g(t)+e^{-it}\hat g(t)+e^{i\pi t}\hat g(t)+e^{-i\pi t}\hat g(t),$$
or
$$(\cos t+\cos\pi t-2)\hat g(t)=0,$$
for real $t$.

The equality $\cos t+\cos\pi t-2=0$ for real $t$ implies $\cos t=1=\cos\pi t$ and hence $t=0$ (because $\pi$ is irrational). So,
the support of $\hat g$ is $\{0\}$. So (see e.g. "For every compact subset $K\subseteq U$ there exist constants
$C_{K}>0$ and $N_{K}\in \mathbb {N}$ such that for all $f\in C_{c}^{\infty }(U)$ with support contained in $K$ [...]" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Definitions_of_test_functions_and_distributions)), we have $\hat g=\sum_{j=0}^n c_j\de^{(j)}$ for some $n\in\{0,1,\dots\}$ and some complex $c_j$'s, where $\de^{(j)}$ is the $j$th derivative of the delta function. So, $g$ is a polynomial. Since $g$ is bounded, it is constant. $\quad\Box$

Comment: This idea also looks like it can be used to prove the mean value formula of harmonic function.

Comment: @katago : Sorry, I don't what "the mean value formula of harmonic function" is.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, using your method seems we can prove $u$ satisfied the mean value property $\Longrightarrow$ $u$ is a harmonic function. If $$
u(x)=\frac{1}{\left|\partial B_r\right|} \int_{\partial B_r(x)} u d S=\frac{1}{\left|B_r\right|} \int_{B_r(x)} u(y) d y
$$, let $\hat{u}$ be the Fourier transform of $u$, then $\hat{u}(x)=\frac{1}{\left|\partial B_r\right|} \int_{\partial B_r(x)} \hat{u}(x)e^{iv} d S=\frac{1}{\left|B_r\right|} \int_{B_r(x)} \hat{u}(x)e^{iv} d y$, then $\hat u(x)(1-\int_{\partial B_r(x)}vdS)=0$.  but I do not know how to move on.

Answer (score 5):

(Compare  [On equation $f(z+1)-f(z)=f'(z)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/114875/on-equation-fz1-fz-fz/114878#114878).)

Plug $g(x)=e^{\lambda x}$. We obtain the characteristic equation:
$$4=2\cosh \lambda+2\cosh\pi\lambda.$$
This has one real root $\lambda=0$ of multiplicity $2$.
This root gives a solution $g(x)=ax+b$ with arbitrary constants $a$ and $b$. Since you are looking for bounded solutions, one has to set $a=0$ and we recover the constant solution of [@katago](https://mathoverflow.net/a/440183). However there are infinitely many others: Let $\lambda=p+iq$ be any complex solution (there are
infinitely many of them). Then any linear combination
$$g(x)=\sum c_ke^{\lambda_k x}$$
gives you a solution. In general, this solution is complex,
but if you want a real solution, notice that $\lambda_k$
come in complex conjugate pairs, so you have
an infinte-dimensional space of real solutions. Now solutions bounded on the real line will correspond to
pure imaginary $\lambda$, but the characteristic
equation does not have pure imaginary roots.

So every bounded solution is indeed constant. That all solutions are linear combinations of exponentials or their limits is a general theorem cited in the reference that I gave in the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

It seems $g$ can only be a constant function. First, $g$  is constant in any shift of set $f(A_x)=\{x+a+b\pi| a,b\in \mathbb N\}$ by Liouville type theorem for discrete harmonic function, and then we need suitable choose the constant to make the function continuous on $\mathbb R/A_x$. but by Dirichlet approximation theorem we can get $g$ is constant on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: If change the condition to sublinear instead of bounded then, the function may not be constant.

Answer (score 4):

Iosef's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/440186) shows the only solutions are constants.

Plug …

*Edgar, G. A.; Rosenblatt, J. M.*, [**Difference equations over locally compact Abelian groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1998197), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 253, 273-289 (1979). [ZBL0417.43006](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0417.43006).

At the end, we construct a nontrivial, continuous, bounded, almost-periodic function $F : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ satisfying
$$
0 = F(x+1)- F(x-1) -\sqrt{2}F(x+2\pi)+\sqrt{2}F(x-2\pi) .
$$